# Is noreferrer enough to secure links?

Tags: xss, phishing, html

Is the use of `noreferrer` enough for links that use `target="_blank"` in order to avoid [reverse tabnabbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabnabbing)

For context here is an explanation of the issue:

- ["Target=_blank - the most underestimated vulnerability ever"](https://www.jitbit.com/alexblog/256-targetblank---the-most-underestimated-vulnerability-ever)
- ["About rel=noopener"](https://mathiasbynens.github.io/rel-noopener/)
- [Steemit article on tabnabbing performed on social media](https://steemit.com/security/@gaottantacinque/steemit-and-the-internet-in-general-is-a-safe-place)

So my question is: what's the consequence of forgetting to add also `noopener` and `nofollow` (that I see used on most websites)?

Are there browsers that are affected by the lack of the last two attributes?

As far as I know [the safest solution is to launch the link in a new tab from a temporary iframe](https://github.com/danielstjules/blankshield) but I see some websites out there using only noreferrer so I was wondering if there's some issue using only noreferrer.

Comment: Please define "secure links". If it is to block child window from accessing parent window, "noreferrer" is enough in almost all browsers. Setting rel="noreferrer" also implies "noopener". Whereas "nofollow" has completely different purpose. There might, however, be older browsers which require "noopener" as well. https://caniuse.com/#search=noopener shows IE and Edge don't support "noopener"

Comment: It is not clear from the question what you consider "secure" and "enough to secure", i.e. what kind of attack you want to defend against. Please describe the context needed to understand what you are asking in your question instead of just linking to some external site.

Comment: For secure links in this case I mean only that it's not possible to redirect the page where the link was opened from.

Answer (score 3):

Only set up `noreferer` if you are privacy-paranoid. `noopener` otherwise. At least one of these two must be present on links pointing to external websites in a new browsing context (there is a `target` value). Add `nofollow` for unrelated (ad partners) websites.

[`noreferrer` includes the behavior of `noopener`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/links.html#link-type-noreferrer), which is the most important one from a security point of view ([see this for an example of attack](https://mathiasbynens.github.io/rel-noopener/)). So `noreferrer noopener` = `noreferrer`.

`nofollow` indicates that [you don't endose any responsibility for this link](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/links.html#link-type-nofollow) so it won't change anything for security ([Search engine might still follow this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19638774/2342518))

Don't do complex things with `iframe` for such a simple result as opening a link (you will break native security in browsers).

Comment: Reading more around I think that the reason for the need of the temporary iframe is Safari: github.com/danielstjules/blankshield#solutions

Comment: The problem is that if only noopener is used it's possible to perform tabnabbing in IE/Edge. If only nofollow is used both IE/Edge and FF are effected. That's why these tests were successful in redirecting the facebook page: https://steemit.com/security/@gaottantacinque/steemit-and-the-internet-in-general-is-a-safe-place

Comment: Regarding iframes I don't think it's that bad to use them as far as they're used in the right way. I wrote more about it here: https://steemit.com/security/@gaottantacinque/steemit-security-check-iframe-tricks
Thanks

Comment: @GaSacchi You don't fix a browser by changing code in your website (since it might break the correctly-behavioring browsers). If Safari/IE/Edge/Whatever is vulnerable to some attacks, the it's Safari/IE/Edge/Whatever team job to fix that, not yours. Using temporary `iframe` is bad since it might force you to allow iframing, so you must alter your `Content Security Policy`. Plus, it might mess with user's browsing history (so would be bad from a UX view)